Pandas Merge with duplicate rows
I have a specific use case where I have 2 dataframes, that have 2 identical rows with the exception of 1 column. The rows that are identical, I need to match with the row that is identical, any non matching rows need to be stacked vertically.
Here is the scenario
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
'id': [0, 1, 2], 
'account': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 
'details': [
    [
        {'a': 'b'},
        {'c': 'd'}
    ],
    [
        {'e': 'f'},
        {'g': 'h'}
    ],
    [
        {'a': 'b'},
        {'c': 'd'}
    ]
]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
'id': [0, 1, 3],
'account': ['a', 'b', 'g'],
'details': [
    [
        {'a': 'b'},
        {'c': 'd'}],
    [
        {'e': 'f'},
        {'g': 'h'}
    ], 
    [
        {'e': 'f'},
        {'g': 'h'}
    ]
],
'attempts': [4, 5, 6]
})

I need to get a data frame that resembles the below. I tried merge but I lose out of rows in df2 with left join that don’t match. If I concat, I need to remove dupes and update the row with the populated attempts field. It is also possible the other way, where df2 has unique rows that need to be merged into df1 as well
result = pd.DataFrame({
'id': [0, 1, 2, 3],
'account': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'g'],
'details': [
    [
        {'a': 'b'},
        {'c': 'd'}
    ],
    [
        {'e': 'f'},
        {'g': 'h'}
    ],
    [
        {'a': 'b'},
        {'c': 'd'}
    ], 
    [
        {'e': 'f'},
        {'g': 'h'}
    ],
],
'attempts': [4, 5, None, 6]
})


These constructors don't work, even after fixing the smart quote to single quote and Dataframe to DataFrame

You're looking for a full outer join on the ['id', 'account', 'details'] columns.
# ensure hashability
df1["details"] = df1["details"].astype(str)
df2["details"] = df2["details"].astype(str)

df = pd.merge(df1, df2, how="outer", on=["id", "account", "details"])

# convert liststring back to list if needed.
from ast import literal_eval

df["details"] = df["details"].apply(literal_eval)


There is no need for lambda here, ~.apply(literal_eval) is enough.

As long as a given id is associated with the exact same information, something you can do is
pd.DataFrame({
    **df1.set_index('id').T.to_dict(),
    **df2.set_index('id').T.to_dict()
}).T.reset_index(names='id')

#    id account                   details attempts
# 0   0       a  [{'a': 'b'}, {'c': 'd'}]        4
# 1   1       b  [{'e': 'f'}, {'g': 'h'}]        5
# 2   2       c  [{'a': 'b'}, {'c': 'd'}]      NaN
# 3   3       g  [{'e': 'f'}, {'g': 'h'}]        6



Any question @Football52 ?
